# Opencv not finding rectangles shape

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find rectangle shapes in this image, but it seems too hard for me. What could i do to accomplish it?

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8HnK.png)

[Those are the rectangles im trying to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woqsw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a website, then I would suggest using selenium or requests to scrape it and find the content.

Although if you still want to use OpenCV to do it, there is a relatively complex way to extract the rectangles. The process will be to use the `cv2.inrange` function to first identify and remove the grey areas, then to look for contours and select the contours that have a similar size. While this is not a general method and will not work in every scenario, it should suffice your specific use case.

The code will look like:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("input.png")
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Found using a website like https://imagecolorpicker.com/
lowerThreshVals = (0, 0, 235)
upperThreshVals = (0, 0, 245)

thresh = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, lowerThreshVals, upperThreshVals)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:

    # Print the contour areas and find the appropriate range. Another approach here could be to look for the 4 contours with closest areas and use those.
    if 200000 > cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 180000:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
        
cv2.imwrite("output.png", image)
```

and should give you the output:
[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options :

- If you have not may rectangle to find, go in the html script of the page, then you'll find the dimensions of the shape
- if you want to automize it in python, i think you import the picture of the website, not the website, so, for that the only solution i know is using an AI code, that can find the shapes by itself. in the source. I guess you can find easily on the web, some free models of AI shaping the rectangle. Here is the code to open do it then :

  ```
    import cv2 as cv
    img_new = cv.imread('file.jpg')
    cv.imwrite(filename='file.jpg')
    cv.imshow("Capturing")
    shape_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('TheAIModelPre-Trained.xml')
    img = cv.imread('file.jpg')
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    shapes = shape_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 8)
    i=0
    for shape in shapes : 
        x, y, w, h = shape
        cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        shape = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv.imshow('shape{}'.format(i), shape)
        i += 1
    cv.imshow('main image', img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
  ```

HTH